# Multi-column Alignment Issue

Tags: spacing, right-to-left, bidi

Trying to create multi column Urdu dictionary.
First entry should be on right side instead of left side.

How align column RTL with preserving text alignment. Also spacing is not consistent between first `\Large` word and second words.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{article} % 10pt font size, A4 paper and two-sided margins
\usepackage[top=3.5cm,bottom=3.5cm,left=3.7cm,right=4.7cm,columnsep=30pt]{geometry} % Document margins and spacings
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{multicol} % Required for splitting text into multiple columns
\usepackage{bidi}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\setmainfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.5]{MehrNastaliqWebRegular.ttf}

\newcommand{\entry}

\begin{document}


\section*{آ}

\begin{multicols} {2}

\setRTL

\entry {\Large آب} \hspace{0.5em} { پانی ،\hspace{0.15em} چمک }
\entry {\Large آب بقا} \hspace{0.5em} {آبِ حیات} {ایسا پانی جس کو پی کر ہمیشہ کی زندگی حاصل ہو جائے۔ کہا جاتا ہے کہ خضرؑ چشمۂ آبِ حیات تک پہنچ گئے تھے اور اس کا پانی پی کر انھوں نے حیات دوام حاصل کی۔}
\entry {\Large آب دارئ صمصام} \hspace{0.5em} {تلوار کی تیزی ،\hspace{0.15em} صمصام بمعنی تلوار }
\entry {\Large آب دینا} \hspace{0.5em} { چمکانا ،\hspace{0.15em} تیز کرنا ،\hspace{0.15em} چمک پیدا کرنا ،\hspace{0.15em} صقیل کرنا ،\hspace{0.15em} سان پر لگانا ،\hspace{0.15em}  صاف کرنا}
\entry {\Large آبگینہ} \hspace{1em}  { شیشہ ،\hspace{0.15em} بلور ،\hspace{0.15em} کانچ ،\hspace{0.15em} شرابِ انگوری ،\hspace{0.15em} کنایہ دل عاشق کا وہ برتن جو پانی کی طرح شفاف اور نازک ہو۔}
\entry {\Large آبلہ پا} \hspace{0.5em} { جس کے پاؤں میں چھالے پڑے ہوں ،\hspace{0.15em}مجازاً تھکا ہوا ،\hspace{0.15em} درماندہ}
\entry {\Large آتش} \hspace{0.5em} { آگ }
\entry {\Large آتش افشانی} \hspace{0.5em} { آگ برسانا ،\hspace{0.15em}شعلے اور نگاریاں بکھیرنا }
\entry {\Large آتش بار} \hspace{0.5em} { شرر بار،\hspace{0.15em} توپ ،\hspace{0.15em} بندوق ،\hspace{0.15em} کسی ہتھیار کے علاوہ زبان کو بھی آتش بار کہتے ہیں۔}
\end{multicols}

\begin{multicols} {2}

\section*{ا}

\setRTL

\entry {\Large ابرام} \hspace{0.5em} { ضد ،\hspace{0.15em} اصرار ،\hspace{0.15em} التماس ،\hspace{0.15em} تقاضا}

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Please advise how i can create `\newcommand{\entry}` for multiple entries with different fontsizes with multiple lengths.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: You need to place
**\setRTL** before **\begin{document}** as bellow: ..... \setRTL \begin{document} ......